# Other procedural material generators for Unity?

Tags: textures, unity, procedural

In the new version of Unity 3.4, unity announced that they would now support procedural materials (which is awesome, by the way). While I was researching it, I found this in the [manual](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Procedural%20Materials.html):

> Allegorithmic's Substance Designer can be used to create Procedural Materials, but there are **other applications** (3D modeling apps, for example) that incorporate the Substance technology and work just as well with Unity.

I don't have Allegorithmic's substance designer and don't plan on buying it soon. What other applications or 3D modeling apps can make procedural materials that work in Unity?

*Edit*: I found that Allegorithmic has a program called Player. But it is on Windows only. I'm on mac.

Comment: I don't think you can take Maya or Max's procedural material to unity.

Comment: Get a copy of some virtualisation software, and then use this Player you mention. I don't know anyone on a Mac who isn't running something like VMWare Fusion or Parallels. It's a worthwhile investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They emailed me.

> 3DS Max and Maya both use substance materials: http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/u/gsearch/results?siteID=123112&catID=123155&id=2088334&qt=substance
>  Take a look there for vids and tutorials.
>   Unfortunately unity cannot import settings for substances edited in Max Maya at present, so you need to set them in both or use a dummy material in the source 3D package - I hope that helps!